# What do people in the computer graphics industry use for ray tracing?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, frameworks, raytracing

I took a **computer graphics course** (graduate level) this past year. We spent the semester **building a ray tracer** and adding features to it. We built **everything from scratch** in C++, presumably for the purpose of gaining a better understanding of the underlying data structures and algorithms. Here's my question: If I were to get a job in industry with computer graphics, **would people think I was crazy if I started building everything from the ground up** for ray tracing like this? Are there graphics **libraries** and **frameworks** similar to OpenGL which support ray tracing? Does OpenGL itself support ray tracing?

My professor for the course is an expert in the fundamentals of computer graphics theory and the relevant mathematics, but doesn't have any understanding of modern frameworks and libraries which are used by professionals for computer graphics. She's more of a scientist than a practitioner.

If I were to use a library to help me out with ray tracing, it would probably be good if it supported distributing the computations to a cluster of computers. I could also use a **book recommendation**, if you know of one which would help **bridge this gap in my understanding**.

Comment: Try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Did **somebody** here order a **large ham**?

Comment: @Matt Ball, GameDev may not be the best forum for this question; Ray tracing is used in the movie industry, but not so much in the video game industry because of it's computationally intensive nature.

Comment: @Gwen Avery We might see more real-time raytracing in/on future GPUs :) NVidia has some pretty demos.

Comment: @pst I've seen those demos! Good stuff!

Comment: Look up "RenderMan" and Maya. There are other professionals ray tracing tools.

Comment: "would people think I was crazy if I started building everything from the ground up for ray tracing like this?" If you're going to work in professional CGI, then yes. However most CGI studios use in-house-software and any unserstanding of the structures of those requires fundamental understanding how raytracing works. So if you want to start a career in professional CGI, knowing how a raytracer works from scratch is a big benefit.

Comment: "Does OpenGL itself support ray tracing?" conceptually OpenGL is a rasterizer drawing API: You send it primtives (points, lines, triangles) and it draws those to the screen – triangle by triangle. There's no concept of a scene or even such mundane things like meshes or triangles. OpenGL is not even a framework; but it is used by many frameworks as rendering backend. While OpenGL doesn't implement raytracing per se, it is possible implementing a raytracer using OpenGL facilities, namely shaders. However those OpenGL based raytracers are not nearly as versatile like the well developed ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I'm sure there are a number of specialized commercial products, I think overall the most widely used package is the open-source [POVRay.](http://www.povray.org) POVRay is powerful, easy to use, scriptable and extensible, and it can do an amazing range of things out of the box. Check out their site for an enormous gallery of ray-traced art, including the scripts used to create some fantastic pieces.

This reads like astroturf, but I swear, I'm just a happy user.

Comment: There are other OSS raytracers, like Yaf(a)Ray and also a few raytracing frameworks.

Comment: @datenwolf do you happen to know the names of some of the raytracing frameworks?